# Connecting to NI USB to 232/4 failure

Tags: c#, serial-port

Currently trying to send basic messages through an NI USB-232/4 to a power supply. While connecting with my code, the messages will not get sent through, and the PORT led remains red/orange.

When connecting with the power supply's code, messages can be received perfectly fine, the PORT led turns green. The power supply reacts to commands given.

When connecting the supplied program trough virtual serial ports to a terminal, the messages sent are identical to the messages my program is sending. When input directly from a terminal window to the power supply, the commands work fine. Again, the port led turns green while connecting through the terminal.

The serial settings, as far as I can tell, are identical to those that both the supplied program and the terminal are using. However, the power supply refuses to accept the messages.

```
public Serial(){
        ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.Enqueue("*IDN?");
        ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.Enqueue("SYST:REM\n");
        ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.Enqueue("INST SECO");
        ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.Enqueue("OUTP 1");
        ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.Enqueue("VOLT 9V");
    }

    public void ListenForVoltageChange()
    {
        string result;
        _serialPort = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort();
        OpenPort();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        while (true) {
            if (!ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.IsEmpty) {
                ThreadSafe.serialVoltage.TryDequeue(out result);
                Debug.WriteLine(result);
                _serialPort.WriteLine(result);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
    public bool OpenPort()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Port Open");
        Debug.WriteLine(_serialPort.IsOpen);
        if (!_serialPort.IsOpen)
        {
            _serialPort.PortName = "COM4";
            _serialPort.BaudRate = 9600;
            _serialPort.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
            _serialPort.DataBits = 8;
            _serialPort.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
            _serialPort.RtsEnable = false;
            _serialPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.None;

            _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
            _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;

            try
            { _serialPort.Open(); }
            catch { return false; }
        }
        return true;
    }
```